# Use of with a spacing

Tags: usage

I have two stones A and B. A is 10 cm away from B. After I made A closer to B , the distance between two stones is 2 cm. I mean   I moved A closer to B, so that there was a space of 2 centimeters between them If I say the sentences below by using “with a space “would I describe this situation correctly?

> I moved A towards B with a spacing of 2 cm between them.

Comment: What is your actual problem?  Are you actually talking to someone about stones, or is this just a made-up example?  Questions are usually clearer if you can give the original context.  The answer that works for stones might not be right for the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

It does not sound like how an American English speaker (or a British English speaker - thank you Kate Bunting) would phrase it.  "with a spacing of 2 cm between them" sounds like something about *how* you moved the stones, like "The cars drove across the field side-by-side with a spacing of 2 m between them", not where they ended up.  I would say

> I moved A towards B, leaving 2 cm between them.

Comment: Nor a British English speaker either.

Comment: Three-year-old olive trees of the variety 'Grappolo 541' were planted with a spacing of three meters between plants and five meters between rows in the area studied.
I saw this sentence in an article I thought my sentence has the same structure as this one.

Comment: @languagelearner  Yes, and "with a spacing of three meters between plants" is *how* they were planted.  In your sentence, "with a spacing of 2 cm between them" describes where they ended up, not *how* they moved.

Comment: @languagelearner Please note that your sentence was fine, it just isn't how a native would express the idea. The idea could be colloquially expressed in a number of ways: I moved A to within 2cm of B, for example, or I closed the gap between A and B to 2 cm. Part of the problem is we don't know the context of your sentence. Is engineering precision required? What is more important for the reader to know: that you moved A or the final distance between A and B?

Comment: @languagelearner planting something with a spacing of x between them is not: move A towards B with a spacing of x between them.